# Listview repeats previus data

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This code tries to display in listview fields of databases, but when he tries to show the part of the search he repeats previous data

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim sqlcon As MySqlConnection
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
 If sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("connected")
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT cod_funcionario, matricula, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, email, telefone, endereco, data_nasc, setor FROM funcionario", sqlcon)
        da.Fill(ds, "funcionario")
        Tabelas.Items.Clear()
        If ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows.Count - 1
                With Tabelas.Items.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(6).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(7).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(8).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(9).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("funcionario").Rows(i).Item(10).ToString)
                End With
            Next
        End If
    Else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql search doesn't have a `where` clause, so it returns every row in funcionario. Is that your intention? Is the repeated data actually in the database?

If the query is repeated in the same function, you might need a `ds.clear` before the second query.

Comment: Its repeats in list view, every time i click returns the same itens. and sorry i put the wrong select here.

Comment: da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT cod_funcionario, matricula, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, email, telefone, endereco, data_nasc, setor FROM funcionario WHERE nome LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", sqlcon)

I want to show the selected values ​​in listview, but each time the button is pushed it repeats the selected values